# Where does God Eater (Anime) fall in the God Eater videogame (Burst) timeline?

Tags: god-eater

According to [God Eater's Entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Eater_(anime)):

> God Eater (Anime) is an anime adaptation of the God Eater video game series.

and in GodEater's Entry in [myanimelist.net](http://myanimelist.net/anime/27631/God_Eater)

> Set in a post-apocalyptic Japan in the year 2071. The world has been mostly destroyed by mysterious monsters known as the Aragami. An organization known as Fenrir was made to exterminate Aragami using 'God Arcs', weapons made from Aragami cells. Those who specialize in exterminating Aragami are known as God Eaters. Their God Arcs originally could only keep a single form, **however a new type has been discovered that can switch between gun and blade form.** Since then, they have been classified new-types and the previous as old-types.

I have already Played the GE Burst in the PSP up until the last chapter which is 10. I've already watched the God Eater Prologue and I plan to watch God Eater Anime. 
The anime is said to be based off the video Games.

so does it follow the story of one of the videogames? (i.e. GE Burst)

The Cast consist of the same characters in the videogame except the New-type guy. however, this rather is similar in GEB which you will play as one of the new-types in the game.
Is God Eater a remake of the videoGame or does it tackle the same story in the videogame.

Would it be a waste to watch the anime if I have already finished the game?
Could you give me at least a short insight to what I can hope to watch in this anime without giving spoilers.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The anime only follows the first God Eater game, so before Burst was released. IIRC